# How to solve this error when building the CATIA CAA RADE code

Tags: catia, caa

We have some custom code currently built against v5 R20. I am setting up a new machine to build the same code against v5 R23. I think I've got everything installed, but when I run our build script (which calls mkmk), I get loads of errors like

```
Error in dictionary C:\CatV5\B23\SP2\intel_a\code\dictionary/CATStrFunctionalInterfaces.iid line 150
Can not add interface '{1C3E6229-7F5D-4d06-A4C7-6A95D6E5B1B4} CATIASfmSuperPlateObject SfmSuperPlate'
```

and

```
# syst-ERROR: [CreateProcess(""C:\Program")]: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to find out where these errors come from?

Answer (score 2):

I saw this exact error when I upgrade from R20 to R22. It was a while ago so I apologize that I don't remember the exact procedure to fix it, however, I do remember all the things I did and still do when upgrading to newer versions so this should help point you in the right direction.

Something I noticed during my troubleshooting of this error was that no matter what I tried I could not get the R20 project to compile in the R22 environment.

What I had to do was create an exact copy of the layout and structure of my existing program. (Create the interface, and then module, as if it was a new program). I changed their names to match the release version: i.e. ITSMyProgram -> ITSMyProgramR22. I then created new UUIDs and renamed the alias by adding the R22 to the original name (this prevented confusion in VBA and C#). Finally I copy the original code variables and methods into the new files. (Note: Only the interface, alias, modules, and class names get renamed - the methods inside should be okay. Also make sure to not overwrite the new UUIDs.) In the C# and VBA side I reference the new alias. 
I followed this same procedure when upgrading to R23 and had no problems compiling and running the code.

If this doesn't work, make sure you have the 64-bit c++ compiler installed in Visual Studio and that you are using 2008 for R22 and above.

Also maybe try running as administrator. For some reason the .tlb file would not register in Windows 7 and running as admin would fix that.

There might be a better solution out there but I prefer this one as I get a new clean interface for each release level of Catia and the underlying code is essentially the same.

Let me know if any of this helped.